# Inserting blank page between pdf pages

Tags: pdfpages

I have used the pdfpages package to insert two separate pdf pages in my document, one after the other. I need to put a blank page in between them, however, neither \newpage nor \clearpage seem to be working. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Try `\clearpage \mbox{} \clearpage` between the commands that insert the pages

Comment: Thanks!, it works perfectly, not the most elegant solution, but it does what I needed :)

Comment: You can also use \strut, \null, \rule{0pt}{0pt} or any other invisible text (like \phantom{nothing here to see}).

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh Would you like to convert your comment into an answer? It sounds as if it solved the problem!

Answer (score 6):

If the `pages` list contains `{}`, then package `pdfpages` inserts an empty page, e.g.:

```
\includepdf[pages={1, {}}]{fileA}% page 1 of fileA, empty page
\includepdf[pages={42}]{fileB}% page 42 of fileB
```

Or

```
\includepdfmerge{fileA.pdf, 1, {}, fileB.pdf, 42}
```

Comment: As of version 0.51, this is mentioned at the bottom of pg 2 of the manual: "To insert empty pages use {}."

Answer (score 4):

Just use`\clearpage \mbox{} \clearpage` between the commands that insert the pages.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to insert a completely blank page at the end of file. This worked for me (including John Kormylo's suggestion using `\phantom{}`):

```
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}   %Remove any text from page
\phantom{}              %Insert a blank page
```

Comment: How does this answer the question the op had?